# Debian: how to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" and "unable to verify the first certificate"?

Tags: debian, ssl, certificate

I have a problem with curl downloading an image from a webserver.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So I tried to investigate with openssl

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.websiteredacted.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = *.websiteredacted.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.websiteredacted.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.websiteredacted.com
verify return:1
---
```

I have a super-updated debian 12.5

How can I fix this?

Comment: There are not sufficient information here. It might be a misconfigured server - check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for problems. It might also be SSL interception by middleboxes (like coporate proxy) - check the certificate shown by `openssl s_client` and compare it with the one SSLLabs reports.

Comment: please, wait before close, I found the problem and the solution. I will post the answer.
your suggestions abous SSLLabs and openssl s_client helped me A LOT.

Answer (score -1):

It was a problem with target host certificate.

SSLLabs complains:

[image]

I fixed doing this

```
cd ~
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.domain.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >domain.com.crt
sudo cp domain.com.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

> note: replace domain.com with the real domain

I want to thanks @steffen-ullrich for his comment which pointed me to the right way

Comment: Your `openssl` command downloads the end-entity (your server) certificate.  You then add it to the server's CA certificates.  Your certificate is _not_ a CA, therefore should not be added.  If that's a Lets Encrypt certificate (for example) you'll be repeating yourself in three months when it renews.  You only add trust-anchors to this file, and _only_ if you trust them.

Comment: I had not a fully understanding of the problem, I must admin. But this worked. But thank A LOT for your explanation.